# Animating AppBar like WhatsApp AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I wanted to know how to achieve the following animation. Where the Tabbar swipe animation is synced with The appBar(In WhatsApp).

[image: Animation in Discussion]

I am able to animate the AppBar. However not able to sync the animation with the swipe animation of the TabBar.

It would be great if someone can help me with it.

I am talking about the animation where the appbar hides by sliding up as we swipe the page to the side. I am able to add the animation of hiding the app by sliding up, however linking the page slide with the appbar slide. Is what i am looking for.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The TabBar widget has a default configuration to show this animation. Just initialize the indicator, indicatorSize and indicatorColor parameters.

```
TabBar(
  indicator: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(50, 51, 60, 1),
  ),
  labelColor: Colors.white,
  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
  indicatorColor: Colors.black,
  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
  tabs: [],
),
```

Comment: I think i was not clear enough on the question my bad. I was talking abt the animation where the appbar hides by sliding up as we slide page. I am able to add the animation of hiding the app by sliding up. however not able to link it to page sliding. I will update the question on more details.

Comment: If you define more detail on your code we can imagine the problem 